# delete specific tag for each submodule

Tags: git, git-submodules

I want to delete tag with same name in my sub modules, to delete remote tag I can use `git push origin :tagname`. however I have about 15 sub modules and this is quite frequent some times and my Jenkins build fails on any stale tag remained. Is there a combination of usage `git for each submodule` and `git push origin :tagname` I can use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Exactly that:

```
git submodule foreach git push origin :tagname
```